# How to setup team city agent on mac?

Tags: macos, teamcity, build-agent

I do not know the steps to setup **TeamCity** agent on **mac** so if anybody did it. Please share your experience.

Comment: Please tell us what you've already tried and what specifically you are having problems with

Comment: We got this working by following the helpful advice from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200561/setting-up-teamcity-to-integrate-to-osx-build-agent

Answer (score 8):

As per the manual, the default setup for OSX TeamCity 10.X - In your terminal:

```
cd TeamCity/bin/runAll

sh runAll.sh start
```

In your browser,

```
http://localhost:8111/
```

Answer (score 4):

There are clear instructions in the [online documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installation), explicitly around [server](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-installingWithTomcat) and [agent](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-UsingLaunchDaemonsStartupFilesonMacOSx) configuration on OSX.

If you want help with a specific problem, then please elaborate with more details.

Comment: I guess what he's saying is that he has no experience with Macs at all (kinda the same position I'm in) and needs to know how to install stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can now install agents (including Mac OS) directly from the TeamCity UI using the Agent Push feature. Just select the unix platform in the config settings.

[Official Docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-InstallingviaAgentPush)

Here is a screenshot from someone using it at [this blog post](https://nftb.saturdaymp.com/today-i-learned-how-to-install-a-teamcity-build-agent-on-a-mac/).

[image]